# How to create a mocked (by jmockit) spring bean?

Tags: spring, jmockit

I am new to jmockit and would like to mock a bean inside my Java based Spring Application Configuration. I thought (better hoped) it would go like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyApplicationConfig {

  @Bean // this bean should be a mock
  SomeService getSomeService() {
    return new MockUp<SomeService>() {@Mock String someMethod() { return ""; }}.getMockInstance();
  }

  @Bean // some other bean that depends on the mocked service bean
  MyApplication getMyApplication(SomeService someService) {
    ....
  }
}
```

But unfortunatly this fails with "*Invalid place to apply a mock-up*".

I wonder if I can generate jmockit mocks inside Spring Configuration classes at all. I need the bean because it is referenced by other beans and the whole Spring Context initialization fails if I do not provide the mock as a Spring bean.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use your regular Spring configuration. In a test class, declare the type to be mocked with `@Capturing`. It will mock whatever the implementation class that Spring used.

Edit: added full example code below.

```
import javax.inject.*;

public final class MyApplication {
    private final String name;
    @Inject private SomeService someService;

    public MyApplication(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String doSomething() {
        String something = someService.doSomething();
        return name + ' ' + something;
    }
}
```

---

```
public final class SomeService {
    public String getName() { return null; }
    public String doSomething() { throw new RuntimeException(); }
}
```

---

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
public class MyRealApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    SomeService getSomeService() { return new SomeService(); }

    @Bean
    MyApplication getMyApplication(SomeService someService) {
        String someName = someService.getName();
        return new MyApplication(someName);
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.inject.*;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import mockit.*;
import org.springframework.test.context.*;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyRealApplicationConfig.class)
public final class MyApplicationSpringTest {
    @Inject MyApplication myApplication;
    @Mocked SomeService mockService;

    @BeforeClass // runs before Spring configuration
    public static void setUpMocksForSpringConfiguration() {
        new MockUp<SomeService>() {
            @Mock String getName() { return "one"; }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void doSomethingUsingMockedService() {
        new Expectations() {{ mockService.doSomething(); result = "two"; }};

        String result = myApplication.doSomething();

        assertEquals("one two", result);
    }
}
```

---

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import mockit.*;

// A simpler version of the test; no Spring.
public final class MyApplicationTest {
    @Tested MyApplication myApplication;
    @Injectable String name = "one";
    @Injectable SomeService mockService;

    @Test
    public void doSomethingUsingMockedService() {
        new Expectations() {{ mockService.doSomething(); result = "two"; }};

        String result = myApplication.doSomething();

        assertEquals("one two", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - will investigate this approach.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work if the mock instance is needed during Spring Context initialization. The question is: How to generate a jmockit mock instance with a defined behaviour outside tests?

Comment: The mocking APIs are intended for use *inside* tests only. But it's not clear to me what the actual problem is. Is Spring *calling* methods on beans during context initialization?

Comment: Yes, during context initialization a referenced bean should be a mock with a defined behaviour. See my question - in the ´getMyApplication´ method I would like to call a method on the ´someService´ mock. I know the design is questionable .... but that is how it is.

Comment: By the way, jmockit is really a great framework but the _inside tests only_ restriction should be mentioned on your [comparison matrix page](http://jmockit.org/MockingToolkitComparisonMatrix.html). At the moment it does seem that jmockit can do anything. But I failed in my first attempt to use it :-( (don't get me wrong - there are many good reasons to use it and I do not wan't to criticize)

Comment: The features and qualities in the comparison matrix are things that should matter in *typical* test suites. In this case, I am not seeing a legitimate reason to apply mocking outside of tests. In particular, I don't see why one would need to have a test-specific `@Configuration` class at all; why not use the real Spring configuration? In that case, mocking should work just fine.

Comment: Not to use the real spring configuration in tests can habe several reasons. E.g. because you do not need to provide setup properties for beans that you will mock afterwards or that you do not want to activate special parts of the application during testing (e.g. job scheduling). Not seeing a reason  to do (or not to do)  something for oneself does in general not mean that anybody else has to think the same. By the way why should mocking only be useful for (unit) testing? You might also deploy your software to (test) environments where you need to mock some parts (staging, ...).

Comment: Thanks for extending your answer. Will have a deeper look next week!

Comment: I see; if the real Spring configuration is too big/complex it might be preferable to create simpler ones for testing. I actually have a lot of experience with Spring, and also Java EE. These days, Spring looks like J2EE: it's just too complicated/hard to use, compared to Java EE 7. My preference is actually not for *unit* tests, but *integration* tests, for which I also employ JMockit, by using `@Tested(fullyInitialized = true)` and the JPA support for connecting to a real (test) database; mocking then gets used for things like JSF `FacesContext` and the JasperReports static factory methods.

Comment: Rogério, thanks for taking the time to provide the full code example. Placing the mock generation in the @BeforeTest method is probably one way to go for me but also your 'no Spring' example looks good. As I said I am new to JMockit and I definitly need some deeper understanding of the framework. For your patience definitely Thanks again.

Comment: I do not know about JUnit, but the above code does not work for TestNG. For once, I get `null two`, meaning one of the two mocking method worked, the other did not. But what’s more, Spring tries to build the context first, meaning that dependendencies of `SomeService` have to be fulfilled as well. For me, that means I have to perform my Spring MVC tests with Mockito, because JMockit falls short.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel Having a `JMockit.createMock(SomeType.class)` would be an inelegant solution, and not very easy to use as it requires you to create a full test configuration for Spring, since you can't use the configuration you already have. In practice, I believe that `@Capturing` should cover 99% of real-world needs, with much less code than a Mockito-based test would take. But if you have a real-world use case which truly *needs* to have these mocks created *before* Spring starts the context, then please open an [issue](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues) in the JMockit project.

Answer (score 2):

[Spring-ReInject](https://github.com/sgri/spring-reinject) is designed to replace beans with mocks.

Comment: Interesting but in my case a have a dedicated Spring Test Configuration and can generate the mock in place (no need to reinject something). If possible I would prefere this attempt but if not I might have a deeper look to your library. Thanks and +1 for the moment!